# Does the series converge or diverge??

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I study the series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-\cos(\sin(n^\alpha))}{\sqrt{n+2}} $$

when $\alpha > 0$ ? Does it diverge or converge?

I can't find any series to compare to and all the criteria I've applied fail.

Comment: It could be useful to rewrite it as $2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2((\sin(n^\alpha))/2)}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

Comment: @Clayton That's the largest.

Comment: Mmmm, put $\alpha = 1$ and $n = 355$ then $1-\cos(\sin(355))$ is something like $10^{-10}$

Comment: @Clayton What if $n^\alpha$ is close to multiples of $\pi$? Then $\sin(n^{\alpha})\approx 0$ and no positive lower bound of the numerator could be derived.

Comment: This question has to do with how close the sequence $(n^\alpha)$ can come to the sequence of multiples of  $\pi $. It would be enough to prove that for a dense enough subsequence they stay within a certain distance.

Comment: Applying Cauchy condensation test we can study $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{n/2} \sin( \sin(2^{\alpha n})/2)$ then it fails the root test because the limit is indeterminate. Is it enough? I don't know...

Comment: Or, most importantly, it fails the necessary condition for the convergence $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2^{n/2} \sin( \sin(2^{\alpha n})/2) \neq 0$

Comment: I think this should be correct, right?

Comment: The [condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) only works for positive **non-increasing** sequences.

Comment: That’s right. Ideas?